# Help with the derivative of squared Frobenius norm of a scalar

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares, scalar-fields

I've seen and calculated that the derivative of the squared frobenius norm is

$\frac{\partial||AX-B||_F^2}{\partial X}=2A^T(AX-B)$ when X is a matrix.

Is this also the case when X is not a matrix, but a scalar  (ex: A.x, each element of A is multiplied with x)? I would think that the trace can't be eliminated in this case and normal matrix derivation rules can't be applied because x isn't a matrix, or do they apply here as well? For example:

$||Ax-B||_F^2 = Tr((Ax-B)^T(Ax-B))= Tr(xA^TAx-B^TAx - xA^TB + B^TB)$

$\frac{\partial||Ax-B||_F^2}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (x^2Tr(A^TA))}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial (xTr(B^TA))}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial (xTr(A^TB))}{\partial x} = 2xTr(A^TA)-Tr(B^TA)-Tr(A^TB)$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. It can be made to appear more like the matrix case
$$2\;{\rm Tr}\Big(A^T\big(Ax-B\big)\Big)$$

Comment: Note that if you use the Frobenius inner product, you get $$\hat{x} := \frac{\langle A, B \rangle}{\langle A, A \rangle}$$ which looks very much like a projection.